# Is there a version of ThemeEnginePlugin for Trac 0.12?

Tags: trac

I am setting up Trac 0.12.2 and looking for the ThemeEnginePlugin. I tried the plugin version 0.11 with PyOrgTheme, also 0.11. When I try to select the alternate theme, the page shows the python.org theme description, but the label between the arrows (in the theme admin page) remains at "Default".

Am I using the right version? And if not, is there a plugin for version 0.12 available now or likely in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is now never version thant 0.11 on [trac-hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/browser/themeengineplugin) i would say no, there is no version for 0.12.

The only thing you could do is open a bug there: http://trac-hacks.org/newticket?component=ThemeEnginePlugin&owner=coderanger